# Progress Indicators

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to perform a progress indicator during request.
I have try

```
function waitOn(){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var panel= app.getElementById("LoadingPanel").setVisible(true);
return app;                             
}

function waitOff(){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var panel= app.getElementById("LoadingPanel").setVisible(false);
return app;      
}

function login(e){
waitOn();
...
waitOff();
return app;
}
```

The loading panel is never displayed.
if I comment the waitOff, the loadingpanel is displayed after the execution of the login function (not usefull)

What i the best way to have this kind of display ?

Vincent

Comment: This wasn't working because any change in the UI becomes effective only after a "return" instruction, Megabyte 1024 's answer has separated functions to get these 2 "returns" precisely ;-)   Note also that you could turn on the "Loading panel" with a client Handler inside your main UI function when you define the button, it would make your script slightly simpler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to use a separate event handler for the `waitOn` function something like

```
function test() {
  var handlerLogin = app.createServerHandler('login');
  var handlerWait = app.createServerHandler('onWaitEvent');
  buttonLogin.addClickHandler(handlerLogin);
  buttonLogin.addClickHandler(handlerWait);
}
function onWaitEvent(e) {
   ...
   waitOn();
   ...
}
function login(e){
  ...
  waitOff();
  return app;
}
```